# Problems of History for my own Shell in C

Tags: c, shell

As a project, I have to make my own shell. I did it but I have some problems with the history feature.

Here's piece of my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char saisie[300], cwd[1024];
    char* nom = getenv("USER");
    char* backup[MAXCMD];
    int boucle = 1, n = 0, i, u = 0, b = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAXCMD; i++) 
    {
        backup[i] = NULL;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT_SZ; i++)
    {
        saisie[i] = 0;
    }
    char* cmd[MAXPARAMS];    //MAXPARAMS is 20

    while( boucle == 1)
    {   
        printf("%s@sam:~ %s> ", nom, (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))));
        fgets(saisie,MAX_INPUT_SZ,stdin);
        printf("\n");
        split_input(saisie, cmd);

        free(backup[u]);
        backup[u] = strdup(saisie);
        u = (u + 1) % MAXCMD;

        b = switchcmd(cmd,backup,b,u);
        start(cmd,b);
        b = 0;                      //débloquage fonction start
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I print the history with this fonction:

```
int historique(char* backup[], int u)
{
    int i = u;
    int place = 1;
    do
    {
        if (backup[i])
        {
            printf("%4d:  %s\n", place, backup[i]);
            place++;
        }
        i = (i + 1) % MAXCMD;
    } while (i != u);
        return 0;   
}
```

B is used to block the execution fonction (start) when user enter "cd" or "history", because it will generate an error.

Here's the fonction triggered when user enters "cd", "history", or "exit":

```
int switchcmd(char** cmd,char** backup, int b,int u)

{
    int i, n = 3, switch_value = 0;
    char* error;
    char* listcmd[n];
    listcmd[0] = "cd";
    listcmd[1] = "exit";
    listcmd[2]  = "history";

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(strcmp(cmd[0], listcmd[i]) == 0)
    {
        switch_value = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}

switch (switch_value)
{
    case 1:
        chdir(cmd[1]);
        b = 1;
        error = strerror(errno);
        if (*error != 0)
        {
            printf("sam: %s: %s\n", cmd[0], error);
        }
        break;

    case 2:

        printf("Bye bye\n");
        exit(0);

    case 3:
        historique((char**)backup,u);
        b = 1;
        break;
}
return b;
}
```

When I execute my shell, and enter these commands successively, they work. **°i1**

```
> clear    
> ls -a -l
> ls -a
> cd ..
> man chdir
```

Then "history" for printing the history, I have this :  **°i2**

```
   1:  clear
   2:  ls
   3:  ls
   4:  cd
   5:  man
   6:  history
```

and I want this output, with all parameters: **°i3**

```
1:  clear
2:  ls -a -l
3:  ls -a
4:  cd ..
5:  man chdir
6:  history`
```

I dont know why, and I don't understand why `strdup` does not duplicate my cmd in backup at it should.

Any help please?

Comment: Here `char* cmd[strlen(saisie)+1];` is the first problem: `saisie` is uninitialized and the `strlen(saisie)` yields undefined behaviour, thus the length cannot be determined and thus the size of `cmd` is wrong. Any result you see is "garbage" because of this.

Comment: See the [mcve] definition -- each question should surround *only one* problem, and have only the shortest code necessary to ask about that single, specific problem. Bringing anything else -- like not waiting for background tasks -- into scope makes your question overbroad, and including code unrelated letting others reproduce your specific problem with history brings it outside the MCVE definition.

Comment: @Pablo I edited the program , but still does not work as it should be

Comment: You've made [an update of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49712756/revisions) but the problem remains, `char* cmd[strlen(saisie)+1];` yields undefined behaviour because `saisie` is uninitialized. Everything that follows is "wrong" because of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: As Pablo is pointing out you can't do strlen() of an uninitialized array; that will just return garbage results. You'd have to initialize the array with something like saisie[0] = 0 if you're wanting it to return 0.

Comment: I'm confused, because @Pablo you are pointing the fact [saisie] is uninitialized and its the reasn why my [strlen()] does not work. I made an update with a loop for initialized with 0, but [saisie] still uninitialized.
I understand I have to initilized [saisie], but after my update I don't see who can I initialized [saisie] again.

Comment: @KILIBIBI you are initializing `saisie` **after** you've done `strlen(saisie)`. You have to initialize first, then you can do `char* cmd[strlen(saisie)+1];`. But the way you initialize `saisie`, it will be an empty string, so `strlen(saisie)` would return 0, so you would be doing `char *cmd[1]` and the size cannot be changed later on. So what's the point of having an array of dimension 1? There is some problem in your logic as well. What is the purpose of `saisie`?

Comment: @Pablo ' saisie ' is used to store the command enter by user.

Comment: And what is the point of `cmd`? Like I said, once you do `char* cmd[strlen(saisie)+1];` the length of the array is fixed and cannot change anymore. And as it stands right now (after your edit), it will have dimension one, so you can store only **1** pointer to `char` in `cmd`. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: When the user command is store in ' saisie ', this command is duplicate and split in array of parameters. And I use ' cmd ' in the execution fonction, with execvp. @Pablo

Comment: You seem to split your input up in words *before* storing it into the history array. That's why only the first word is stored. Move the store line *above* `split_input`.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks alot, now I have the output I was expecting !

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable names (and parameter names) should indicate `usage` or `content`  Almost all of the names in the posted code are meaningless, even in the current context  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) consistently indent the code, suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  4) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line

Comment: when calling `strdup()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value and when done with that duplicated string, pass the pointer to `free()` to avoid a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

> When the user command is store in ' saisie ', this command is duplicate and split in array of parameters. And I use ' cmd ' in the execution fonction, with execvp.

Then there is your big problem, `cmd` has a fixed length of 1, if you use that to stored the command arguments for `execvp`, then you can only store one thing: `NULL`.

You have two options:

1. Use a large fixed size, for example `char *cmd[100]` where you can store up
   to 99 arguments and no more. This is the easiest solution but it is not flexible
   enough. Although some systems have a limit on the number of arguemnts you can
   pass to a new process, I don't know if there is a limit for all systems,
   [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) and [this](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) might help you there.
2. Dynamically create an array of `char` pointers depending on the command line.
   This is more work but this is also the more flexible solution. Assuming that
   your command line does not have support for pipes (`|`) and redirections (`<`,
   `<<`, `>`, `>>`), then `split_input` could look like this:

   ```
   char **split_input(const char *cmd)
   {
       if(cmd == NULL)
           return NULL;

       char **argv = NULL, **tmp;

       char *line = strdup(cmd);
       if(line == NULL)
           return NULL;

       const char *delim = " \t\n";

       char *token = strtok(line, delim);
       if(token == NULL)
       {
           free(line);
           return NULL;
       }

       size_t len = 0;

       do {
           char *arg = strdup(token);
           if(arg == NULL)
           {
               free_argv(argv);
               free(line);
               return NULL;
           }

           tmp = realloc(argv, (len + 2) * sizeof *argv);

           if(tmp == NULL)
           {
               free_argv(argv);
               free(line);
               return NULL;
           }

           argv = tmp;
           argv[len++] = arg;
           argv[len] = NULL; // argv must be NULL terminated
       } while(token = strtok(NULL, delim));

       free(line);
       return argv;
   }

   void free_argv(char **argv)
   {
       if(argv == NULL)
           return;

       for(size_t i = 0; argv[i]; ++i)
           free(argv[i]);
       free(argv);
   }
   ```

   Now you can use it like this:

   ```
   while( boucle == 1)
   {   
       printf("%s@sam:~ %s> ", nom, (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))));
       fgets(saisie,MAX_INPUT_SZ,stdin);
       printf("\n");
       char **argv = split_input(saisie);

       if(argv == NULL)
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot split command line, not enough memory\n");
           continue;
       }

       free(backup[u]);
       backup[u] = strdup(argv[0]); // <-- passing argv[0], not argv
                                    // but perhaps what you really want
                                    // is strdup(saisie)
       u = (u + 1) % MAXCMD;

       b = switchcmd(argv,backup,b,u);
       start(argv,b);
       b = 0;                      //débloquage fonction start
       free_argv(argv);
   }
   ```

You are also doing

```
backup[u] = strdup(cmd);
```

but the problem is that `cmd` is an array of `char` pointers, `strdup` expects a
`const char*`, you are passing the wrong type. It should be `strdup(cmd[0])` or
`strdup(saisie)` if you want to store the whole command.

Comment: I edited whit **°i1** **°i2** **°i3**.

I tried both options you gave me, they "work", but I have the same issues from the begining. When I enter same comands then **°i1**, with `history` for priting the history, I still have this output **°i2**

Its my problem. I want output **°i3**.

With `strdup(cmd[0])` and  `strdup(saisie)', I still don't have history with all parameters . @Pablo